# Adding options to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some options to a function in JavaScript. Basically, I would like to return different results based on options on call. I am not sure how to do this but I thought that following code can take care of it which it can not:

```js
 function optional(elem){
 opt1: function(){ console.log( elem/15);},
 opt2: function(){ console.log( elem/50);}
 }


optional(100){opt1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Would you just put:

function optional ( elem ) {
let funcs = {
 opt1: function(){ console.log( elem/15);},
 opt2: function(){ console.log( elem/50);}
 }

Comment: do you mean you want to be able to pass the options into the function as a parameter? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have object keys mapping to your functions and pass the function key you want to invoke as other parameter like

```
function optional(elem, trigger) {
  var obj = {
    opt1: function() {
      console.log(elem / 15);
    },
    opt2: function() {
      console.log(elem / 50);
    }
  };

  return obj[trigger];
}


optional(100, 'opt1')();
```

---

Other way you can achieve this in a very compact way is to pass an object with respective params like

```
function optional(obj) {
  //don't forget to validate the object you get
  //ex: key exist or not, or the value is int as expected or it's a string and so on
  console.log(obj.val / obj.divideBy);
}

optional({
  val: 100,
  divideBy: 15
});
```

This way, you don't have to declare hundreds of functions which you might end up with what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

somo little idea is this:

```
function optional(elem, opt){
{
 opt1: function(){ console.log( elem/15);},
 opt2: function(){ console.log( elem/50);}

}
return this[optelm, ]
 }
```

which elm will be 'opt1', 'opt2'.... pasing as string to method optional like this:

```
optional(elm, 'opt1');
```

Comment: Thanks Alvaro but how can I pass the value to `optional()`

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
function optional ( opt ) {
  let funcs = {
    opt1: function( data ){ console.log( data/15);},
    opt2: function( data ){ console.log( data/50);}
  }

  return funcs [ opt ];
}

optional ( "opt2" ) ( 100 ) // should trace out "2"
```

"optional ( "opt2" ) return the function indicated by that opt name. 
"(100)" then feeds a value (in this case 100) into that function and executes it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the switch-case approach...  Less "func-ception"

```
function optional(elem, opt) {
    switch(opt) {
        case 1:
            console.log(elem / 15);
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log(elem / 15);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("undefined");
            break;
    }
}
```